# How to turn a single row to multiple row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

ex:

the column 'genre' has a row of data:

```
+----------------------------+
|            genres          |
+----------------------------+
|   action, adventure, drama |       |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

my desired output will be a column that holds the following data:

```
+------------+
|    genre   | 
+------------+
| action     |
| adventure  | 
| drama      | 
+------------+
```

how do I do it in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a split function as below to get your expectation part of values by comma.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `SPLIT_STR` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR`(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '') $$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

then use `UNION ALL` to combine those result as below

**Query #1**

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(genres, ',', 1) genre  FROM T 
UNION ALL
SELECT SPLIT_STR(genres, ',', 2) FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT SPLIT_STR(genres, ',', 3) FROM T;
```

| genre |
| --- |
| action |
| adventure |
| drama |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/51z4T2DnpsT8VWh9PH9852/0)

**NOTE**

I would suggest you re-design your table scheme because it was bad for store value by comma and you need to convert as rows.